# Реализация подгрузки контента

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется такой код:
https://pastebin.com/7m8PfCJi

Controller:

```
public function catalogAction()
    {
        $count = 10;
        if (strcasecmp($_POST['action'], 'loadContent') == 0) {
            $count = $_POST['id'];
        }
        $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->productsCount());
        $vars = array(
            'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
            'count' => $count,
            'list' => $this->model->productsList($this->route,(int)$count),
        );
        if (strcasecmp($_POST['action'], 'loadContent') != 0) {
            $this->view->render('Каталог', $vars);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    // Вставляем полученный контент в HTML блок с id="content"
    $("#content").load("/catalog/",{action:"loadContent", id:id});
});
</script>
<div  class="catalog-page-title">
    <h1 class="page-title"><a href="/">Главная</a> > Каталог</h1>
</div>

<?php if (empty($list)): ?>
    <div class="empty-container">
        <p>Каталоги ненайдены</p>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>

        <div class="catalog-container">
        <?php foreach ($list as $val): ?>
            <div class="catalog-block">
                <div class="catalog-img-block">
                    <a class="" href="/catalog/<?php echo $val['id']; ?>">
                        <img src="public/images/1.jpg" alt="Изображение">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="catalog-info-title">
                    <a href="/catalog/<?php echo $val['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($val['title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    <div id="getContent">
        <a class="read-more" data-id="<?php echo $vars['count']+10; ?>" href="#">Подробнее</a>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при выполнении функции load("/catalog"... подгружается контроллер с функцией catalogAction и я никак не могу придумать как из нее подгрузить данные

Comment: Объясните фразу **я никак не могу придумать как из нее подгрузить данные**. Какие данные?

Comment: данные из $vars

Comment: А ваш метод `render` как устроен? Есть ощущение, что он `extract` делает и соответственно, каждый ключ массива - переменная

Comment: да, так и есть, вот ссылка на весь код https://github.com/php-youtube/php-blog, я оттуда всю основу взял

Answer (score 0):

В случае с `extract` нельзя обращаться к `$vars`, так как ключи этого массива будут самостоятельными переменными. Надо обращаться к `$count`, `$list` и тд.

Хотя у меня есть ощущение, что никак не получишь их. Есть вариант возвращать через ob_start (кеширование) html и переменные по JSON. Ну это костыль

Почему? Потому что твое обращение к контроллеру вернется как `html`, а переменных уже не будет (вероятно), так что надо json отправлять еще с переменными, если хочешь.

Comment: я решил так, если скрипт ничего не передает выполняется функция $this->view->render которая отображает страницу, а если скрипт выполняется то выполняется новая функция $this->view->render2, которая содержит макет под данные, а данные передаются массивом $vars